# Struct without constructor

Tags: c#, struct, constructor

I am trying to use a dll where the following structure exists:

```
 public struct MyStruct
 {
     public int Day;
     public int Hour;
     public int Month;
     public int MonthVal;
 }
```

In my code I am trying to assign values to these variables:

```
MyStruct MS; OR MyStruct MS = new MyStruct(); and then do
MS.Day = 1;
MS.Hour = 12;
MS.Month = 2;
MS.MonthVal = 22;
```

Problem is, MS cannot be assigned values, and because the struct has no constructor, I cannot do

```
 MyStruct ms = new MyStruct(1, 12, 2, 22);
```

So, how do I get values into the structure?

Comment: You should *create* a constructor that looks like that.  And then when you do, make those fields read-only.  (Or just use `DateTime`.)

Comment: @Servy I have no access to the dll to make such a change. Or can it be done in my code?

Comment: var ms = new MyStruct();  etcetera.

Comment: This isn't best practice (mutable structs), but you definitely can assign values to the fields of that struct.

Comment: @Hans Thanks! Can't believe I missed the obvious. Just spent several hours on it. This what severe lack of sleep does to you :)

Comment: Alternatively, var ms = new MyStruct { Day = 1, Hour = 12, etc };

Comment: @GabrielIsenberg Which is essentially the same as what the OP posted.  Other than the evils of mutable structs I don't see an issue here at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In my code I am trying to assign values to these variables
>
> ```
> MyStruct MS = new MyStruct();
> MS.Day = 1;
> MS.Hour = 12;
> MS.Month = 2;
> MS.MonthVal = 22;
> ```

This approach works perfectly ([demo](http://ideone.com/SuLDZr)). However, the two approaches described below are better:

If you do not want to define a constructor, this syntax would save you some typing, and group related items together in a single initializer:

```
MyStruct MS = new MyStruct {
    Day = 1,
    Hour = 12,
    Month = 2,
    MonthVal = 22
};
```

If you are OK with defining a constructor, do this instead:

```
public struct MyStruct {
    public int Day {get;}
    public int Hour {get;}
    public int Month {get;}
    public int MonthVal {get;}
    public MyStruct(int d, int h, int m, int mv) {
        Day = d;
        Hour = h;
        Month = m;
        MonthVal = mv;
    }
}
```

This approach would give you an immutable `struct` ([which it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441309/335858)), and a constructor that should be called like this:

```
MyStruct MS = new MyStruct(1, 12, 2, 22);
```

Comment: @Moderator: I have a follow up question concerning constructor-less structs with a uint array: can I ask it here or do I start a new thread?

Comment: @PeterJ I am not a moderator, but the decision is up to you. If you think that your follow-up question does not change the substance of your original question, you are welcome to edit your question; however, as far as potential answers go, this is not likely to generate much new interest. On the other hand, if you think that your follow-up question is sufficiently different (say, it's more about embedding arrays into structs than about structs without constructors) then asking a new question is a better alternative.

Comment: @PeterJ I can tell you upfront that embedding arrays into structs is a rather questionable practice.

Comment: I fully accept that, but that is what I have to deal with in the dll I am forced to work with on this task.  I will ask a new question then, thanks very much